# Convert a filetype to its original state

Tags: file-type, typeconverter

How can I change a file type?

A year ago I wrote a few articles that should be viewed in any text type of program.  however, I recently opened them and they are viewed in symbols and alphanumeric characters.  In linux os, the 'file' is now in an archived folder type that contains .xml files. in windows os it is 'file' as type of file. it has no extension.

Is there any way to recover the original readable alpha-numeric information in these files?

My preference would be to salvage the original information than redo.

Comment: oops.. i meant to say wrote, not write, in the first sentence.

Comment: You can click the edit button below your question to fix any typos.

Comment: Though I did provide an answer that hope will point you in the correct direction, I have a feeling this question may be deemed off topic for Stack Overflow, it may potentially be on topic on SuperUser

Answer (score 0):

First off the extension doesn't actually mean anything for the information of the file, it's only purpose is as a hint to the OS for deciding which application should be used in opening the file. You can prove this by renaming something like an exe to have a txt extension which will then open in notepad as a lot of seemingly random characters; renaming it back to exe will allow it to run again.

Based on your description the files you mention are some form of binary file, the bad news with that is you need to know either what application was used to create the file in order to be able to open it or what the original file extension was (which would be a hint to the former).

If you don't know either of those pieces of information you can of course use trial and error by guessing what extension it might be, renaming it, then opening it with the associated application and seeing if it worked.

Comment: thanks. i had tried adding .txt at the end and then opening it in gedit of linux just hoping to recover any readable alpha-numeric but the file still displayed random characters. i'll keep trying. i was hoping for a cmd line to fix or convert the characters/file structure to the appropriate.  the files are just written articles (no scripts, codes or executable writing) :-(

Comment: Could the document have been a pdf or word doc perhaps, both of those are binary and would not be readable as a .txt; if you're not sure try renaiming it with either .pdf, .doc or .docx.